# Wheels head lights brake lights stuck from ghsn28 car custom command when transferring from 1.12 to 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had an old 1.12 car custom command, and I moved to 1.13 and tried to break the car. Now the tires and headlights are stuck, what can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Commands don't update properly from 1.12 to 1.13, you have to adapt them to the new syntax yourself. I recommend not upgrading worlds that rely heavily on command blocks or functions.

Answer (score 1):

The wheel is probably an armor stand. To get rid of it you can use this command:

```
/kill @e[type=armor_stand,distance=..5]
```

- The `/kill` command kills specified entities
- `@e` means to target all entities
- `type=armor_stand` means to only target armor stands
- `distance=..5` means to only target entities within a block radius of 5 or under.

If it isn't an armor stand, you can find out what entity it is by going into spectator mode.